# How do I get the DBContext in the ApplicationModule Initialize() method

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to configure automapper.Collections for my aspnet boilerplate core project, how do I get the DBContext to configure:

cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps> ();

ie in:

```
   public override void Initialize()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(ApplicationModule).GetAssembly();

        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(thisAssembly);

        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
            // Scan the assembly for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile
            cfg => {
                cfg.AddProfiles(thisAssembly);
                cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
                cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkCorePrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<dbcontext>> ();
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Erm, type it out?

Comment: Ok, thought I needed to get it from Abp, added 
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 
and got past that issue.

but now I'm getting the following exception:

InvalidOperationException: Use AddEntityFrameworkCoreKeys instead of using SetGeneratePropertyMaps.

for this 

cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkCorePrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<DbContext>> ();

but I don't seem to have an implementation of AddEntityFrameworkCoreKeys

Comment: 1. Use the DbContext implemented in your *.EntityFrameworkCore project. 2. It should be `UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel`.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I've defined as follows but I'm not getting the syntax right, what am I missing?

cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<GenerateEntityFrameworkCorePrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<MyDbContext>>();

Comment: `cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyDbContext>();`

Comment: I still seem to be missing something, I get the following compile error when using the above:   Error CS0310 'MyDbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'MapperConfigurationExpressionExtensions.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<TContext>(IMapperConfigurationExpression)'

Answer (score 0):

My solution was using the Abp DefaultDbContextResolver

```
// We are just creating the DbContext for the model
// So we don't need a connection string
var dbContext = IocManager
    .Resolve<DefaultDbContextResolver>()
    .Resolve<MyDbContext>(null, null);
cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel(dbContext.Model);
```